# codigniter: always throw You did not select a file to upload. not able to update

Tags: php

Hello i need help below is my code

It doesn't update any think except the avatar always display error You did not select a file to upload.
 don't know how to solve it please help

```
    if($this->input->post()){   
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('avatar','avatar','callback_multiple_image_upload|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('overview','overview','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('history','history','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('education','education','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('joining','joining','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('hobbies','hobbies','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('experience','experience','trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('skills','skills','trim');

  /* if($this->input->post('avatar')){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('avatar','avatar','callback_multiple_image_upload|trim');
    }else{} */
    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
            // check if avatar is uploaded
        $images = ($this->session->userdata('uploaded_images'))?$this->session->userdata('uploaded_images'):array();
        if($this->session->userdata('uploaded_avatar')){
            $user['avatar'] = $this->session->userdata('uploaded_avatar');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('uploaded_avatar');
        }

        $data = array(
                'avatar' => ($images)?$images[0]['file_name']:'',
                'thumb' => ($images)?$images[0]['thumb']:'',
                'overview' =>$this->input->post('overview'),
                'history' =>$this->input->post('history'),
                'education' =>$this->input->post('education'),
                'joining' =>$this->input->post('joining'),
                'hobbies' =>$this->input->post('hobbies'),
                'experience' =>$this->input->post('experience'),
                'skills' =>$this->input->post('skills'),


        );
        $abc = $this->user_model->update($user_id,$data,'user_id');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','User updated successfully');
        redirect('admin/staff/edit/'.$user_id);

    }
}



    public function multiple_image_upload()
{
    $config = array();
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/user_avatars/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 10000;
    $config['max_width']            = 10240;
    $config['max_height']           = 7680;

    //$images = array();

    if(isset($_FILES['avatar']) && ($count = count($_FILES['avatar']['name'])) > 0)
    {
        $files = $_FILES;
        $images = array();
        /* check if folder with year exists*/
        $current_year = date('Y');
        $path = './uploads/user_avatars/'.$current_year;

        if(is_dir($path)){
            /* do nothing */
        }else{
            /* create directory */
            @mkdir( $path , 0755, true );
        }

        $images = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100000';
            $config['max_width']  = '102400';
            $config['max_height']  = '76800';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ($this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();

                /* create thumbnail */
                $this->load->helper('image_thumb_helper');
                generate_image_thumb($data['full_path'],$path,$data['file_name']);

                /* add to database */                   
                $images[$i]['file_name'] = $current_year.'/'.$data['file_name'];
                $images[$i]['thumb'] = $current_year.'/thumb_'.$data['file_name'];
            }else{
                $this->form_validation->set_message('multiple_image_upload',$this->upload->display_errors());
                return false; 
            }    
        }

        $this->session->set_userdata('uploaded_images',$images);
        return true;
    }
    else{

      return true;
    }
}
```

please provide me solution m not able to remove this error :(

Comment: you get such error while you try to upload large file. usually in php.ini file limit is set to 8M and if you try to upload larger file then you will get this error. chekc php.ini for below entities
`memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M`

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 750M already

Comment: check folder permission...

Comment: Change:

<?php echo form_open_multipart('../post_func');?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you are using multifile upload. please try bellow one for "for loop"

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
    {

         $_FILES['avatar_solo']['name'] = $_FILES['avatar']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['avatar_solo']['type'] = $_FILES['avatar']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['avatar_solo']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['avatar_solo']['error'] = $_FILES['avatar']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['avatar_solo']['size'] = $_FILES['avatar']['size'][$i];

        $config['upload_path'] = $path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100000';
        $config['max_width']  = '102400';
        $config['max_height']  = '76800';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('avatar_solo'))
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();

            /* create thumbnail */
            $this->load->helper('image_thumb_helper');
            generate_image_thumb($data['full_path'],$path,$data['file_name']);

            /* add to database */                   
            $images[$i]['file_name'] = $current_year.'/'.$data['file_name'];
            $images[$i]['thumb'] = $current_year.'/thumb_'.$data['file_name'];
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('multiple_image_upload',$this->upload->display_errors());
            return false; 
        }    
    }
```

Comment: it updates every thing but delete's the image and not update it again

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you, You mean do you want to remove image from existing files . Then you can use "unlink($abs_path)" function

Comment: No, you understand me wrong your answers works well as i wanted but it deletes the image from database as i update anything i don't want that

Comment: If you dont want to update image just not pass those into array

$data = array(                
                'overview' =>$this->input->post('overview'),
              .....
);
    
 if($images){
  $data['avatar'] = $images[0]['file_name'];
        $data['thumb'] = $images[0]['thumb'];
 }

Comment: glad :) it worked but display undefined variable $count which is inside the for loop

Comment: can you please tell me how to avoid undefined variable error

Comment: I think you wont get the problem..Anyway add @ infront of count. so it looks like  @$count

Comment: is there any other alternative except the @

Comment: please again i nedd help image upload function doesn't upload image not even in folder and db too

Comment: $_FILES['avatar_solo']['name'] = $_FILES['avatar']['name'][$i]; here it display error